# Does flash-player API have "get the screen resolution" feature?

Tags: browser, youtube, adobe, flash

Could flash script that run in the browser (like Youtube) find out screen resolution ?

I wonder if Youtube could (at least) point out to people who watch 1080p videos on roughly 720p laptop's screens.

Or maybe youtube should just hide 1080p option to lower resolutions screen.

Answer (score 0):

Flash exists on an html element, and inherits the dimensions which are given to it, so it can't be done. However you can use an ExternalInterface to receive this information from a JavaScript function which should be created in the same html file.

Flash can check it's maximum available resolution by the parameters in the main stage variable of [stageWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageWidth) and [stageHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight)

Comment: How could it be then, that flash apps can go Fullscreen even when browser doesn't support HTML5's Fullscreen feature ?  It have to have more permissions...

Comment: To be able to go fullscreen you also need permissions from the html element. You can check out this detailed post [Exploring full-screen mode in Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html)

Comment: Permission from html element ? How could it be when there was not html5 full-screen feature ?  Isn't just browser give special permission to plugins back then ?